# Mercurial tracking file removal

Tags: mercurial, synchronization, rm

Can I say "deleting this file is part of this commit" in hg? I know about `hg rm`, but it seems to only *remove tracking* of a file, not *track its removal*.

Concretely, if I have a repository containing file `t` in two places (A and B), and at A say `hg rm t`, and commit, and push, and at B say `hg pull -u`, file `t` will be there. :-(

I can't imagine anyone wanting that behaviour actually, but that's not the question. The question is: can I somehow sync *working trees* via `hg`, or only *existing* files?

Comment: I do not see this behaviour locally: if you update to the same changeset in B, 't' should be gone. Are you sure you have updated to the correct revision in B?

Comment: Hm, you're right. What probably happened is that t had some "uncommitted changes" at B (in fact it was just opened and closed in the editor, but probably that was enough to mark it modified). Still, my puzzlement remains. Shouldn't hg warn me "you have uncommitted changes" instead of silently discarding the committed removal? Merge of "deleted" and "changeset C" isn't "changeset C". Especially if C wasn't committed at all. (And a SO question: should I now change my question, or make a new one?:)

Comment: I believe when one changeset deletes a file, while another changes the file, you should get a question 'other side deleted, this file changed, what do you want to do'.
However, I'm not sure if this is the case for uncommitted changes.
Regarding the question: no idea, I'm not an expert ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you pull, the deleted file will be deleted in your history, but not in your sources, locally. You have to update (hg up) for that.

If you have modified this file, and not committed it, Mercurial will tell you that you have uncommited changes, it won't be able to update.

Once it's commited, the deleted file will conflicts with the modified file, you'll be asked either you want to keep the modified file, or delete it.

Comment: > If you have modified this file, and not committed it, Mercurial will tell you that you have uncommited changes, it won't be able to update. < Are you sure this happens when I do `hg pull -u`? Because my experience doesn't match this. :-(